# In Microservices environment, if there are multiple services tied up together in a Chaining manner then how below scenarios will be covered

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

**If Microservice 1 ---> calls Microservice 2---> calls Microservice 3 and so on…**

What should be the transaction rollback approach if let says the call between Microservice 2 and Microservice 3 breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be to implement the Saga Pattern. You can check here for a more detailed explanation https://www.baeldung.com/cs/saga-pattern-microservices